# Instantiate a class in MVC 5 gives error [class] does not contain a definition for [member] and no extension method [member] ... could be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a class defined in a model:

```
public class OfficeData
{
public int ReportID;
public DateTime? LastReported;
public string ReportedBy;
}
```

and this method to instantiate the class in the model:

```
public IEnumerable<OfficeData> GetOfficeData(int OfficeId)
{
MyContext db = new MyContext();
var officeData = db.Database.SqlQuery<OfficeData>("get_data @OfficeID", new SqlParameter("OfficeID", OfficeId)).Select(data => new OfficeData { ReportID = data.ReportID, LastReported = data.LastReported, ReportedBy = data.ReportedBy};
return officeData;
}
```

and I am calling the method in a controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
OfficeModel officeModel = new OfficeModel;
...
MyServiceLayer serv = new MyServiceLayer; // the service layer class holds the method
var officeData = serv.GetOfficeData(officeModel.OfficeID);
officeModel.ReportID = officeData.ReportID;
officeModel.LastReported = officeData.LastReported;
officeModel.ReportedBy = officeData.ReportedBy;
...
}
```

This is my first project in MVC and I'd like to understand what's going on here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? What are the namespaces of the classes?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, the error is at compile time against the attempts to assign values in the ActionResult method.

Comment: And the namespaces are:

Comment: Just in case you didn't know and you're new to C# as well, C# is case-sensitive. So `ReportID` and `ReportId` and `REPORTID` are three different things. You might want to make sure these are all spelled right. On that note, can you edit your post to include the `OfficeModel` class? The simplest explanation if all namespaces are ok and it's picking up the right `OfficeModel` class is that `ReportID` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, misuse of the enter key. The model, service layer class and controller are all in own namespaces and I have all the using statements correctly in place. I'm using the same model - business layer - controller approach with other data and retrieving it successfully so I don't think it's a missing reference or namespace conflict. What is unique to this set of data though is that I'm retrieving it from the db with raw sql whereas the other data reads are against repositories and in one case against values stored in web.config.

Comment: Hi @lc, thanks for reply. My C# is OK, just a bit lost with the MVC approach. The case uses follow corporate guide. If I do the below in the controller itself the results are OK, so I guess my problem is something to do with returning the IEnumerable<OfficeData>:

Comment: The below being var data = db.Database.SqlQuery("stored_proc @OfficeID", new SqlParameter("OfficeID", OfficeId)).Single();

Comment: FWIW earlier on when I was trying various things in the GetOfficeData method, I was also getting can't implicitly convert IEnumerable type Models.OfficeData to Models.OfficeData, which AFAIK means that the type of my anonymous type can't be converted to my class type.

Comment: Ahhhhh that's it. Your last comment explains it. If you hover over `var` you'll notice `officeData` is an `IEnumerable<OfficeData>` because that's what your method returns. Assuming you just expect a single row, you should call `FirstOrDefault()` on the enumerable. Or otherwise loop through them or figure out which row you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetOfficeData` returns an `IEnumerable<OfficeData>`:

```
public IEnumerable<OfficeData> GetOfficeData(int OfficeId)
```

so the inferred type of `officeData` is also `IEnumerable<OfficeData>`. You can see this if you hover over the `var` keyword (or `officeData`, I forget which you have to hover over).

```
var officeData = serv.GetOfficeData(officeModel.OfficeID);
```

So the compiler is complaining that `IEnumerable<OfficeData>.ReportID` doesn't exist. Which it most likely doesn't. Did you mean to call `FirstOrDefault()` or possibly enumerate through the collection via a call to `Select` or a loop?